# How to match a number with a group possibly in square brackets?

Tags: java, regex-group

I need to grab the number from strings like these:

- "prefix.[10].suffix
- "prefix.10.suffix"

My first intuition was to do this:

```
\w+\.((\[(?<number>\d+)\])|(?<number>\d+))\.\w+
```

But this fails with an error: "? A subpattern name must be unique".

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/Ttp0a3/1)

Comment: What's wrong with `find`ing with `"(\\d+)"`?

Comment: This seems too generic, I would like it to match as closely as possible, so it won't confront with the other groups

Comment: What is [your actual GOAL](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)
with this?

Comment: We can only work with the given examples. Those examples are sufficiently simple to capture your numbers with `input = input.replaceAll("\\D", "");`

Comment: Re: But this fails with an error: "? A subpattern name must be unique".  
  
I've found this restriction is relaxed if the duplicate named capturing groups are not in the same disjunction alternative, so for any string input, only one named capturing group can actually be matched, but this is a much newer feature and it lookls like it's not supported in Java regex  
  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Named_capturing_group

Comment: So this https://regex101.com/r/DQk9Q6/1 doesn't work for Java

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine, but, you can't have 2 paren groups and name them both 'number'. I know you want to grab 'whichever one matched' but that's just not how regexes work - you have to fetch group 1 and if that is `null`, fetch group 2 instead. Name them what you want, or don't name them:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\.((\\[(\\d+)\\])|(\\d+))\\.\\w+");

Matcher m = p.matcher("prefix.[10].suffix");
if (m.matches()) {
  String raw = m.group(1);
  if (raw == null) raw = m.group(2);
  return Integer.parseInt(raw);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, different group names will work, but I'm looking for a way how to do with just one, it seems like "Duplicate named capturing groups" is a new feature, and not supported in java regex (though it works in other places https://regex101.com/r/DQk9Q6/1), so I wonder if there is a workaround for Java.  https://github.com/tc39/proposal-duplicate-named-capturing-groups

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the number, then you don't need the quantifier `+` for the word characters `\w+` as 1 will also suffice.

Java supports lookaround assertions which would allow you to use an alternation for both scenario's and get a match only without using a group.

```
(?<=\w\.)\d+(?=\.\w)|(?<=\w\.\[)\d+(?=]\.\w)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\w\.)\d+(?=\.\w)` Assert a word char followed by a dot to the left, match 1+ digits and then assert a dot and a word char to the right
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\w\.\[)\d+(?=]\.\w)` Same as the first part, but now with `[` and `]` in the assertions

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ogljOK/1)

In Java with the doubled escapes:

```
String regex = "(?<=\\w\\.)\\d+(?=\\.\\w)|(?<=\\w\\.\\[)\\d+(?=]\\.\\w)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\.\[*(.*)\]*\.)` this will match with .[10]. or .10.

There will be two groups in the match. Group 1 will be .[10]. and Group 2 will be 10 You can get your required value in group 2.

`\.` - Expecting a dot

`\[*` - Expecting 0 or more of [

`(.*)` - Match with any character

`\]*` - Expecting 0 or more of ]

`\.` - Expecting a dot

Basically (.*) this group will capture anything between .[ and ]. where [ and ] are optional. You can replace [ and ] here either with any characterset according to your requirement.

For example if there can be any character except digits in place of [ and ]

```
(\.[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*\.)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will also match a single bracket e.g. "test.[10.test", what is not desirable.

Comment: In that case it becomes the case of balancing paranthesis which would be handled by coding in much cleaner way. You can extract anything between dots and then iterate through that string and if you encounter opening paranthesis push in a stack and if closing pop it, any integer in between can be stored in a variable. At the end if stack is empty, the integer is legit otherwise discard it. Ofcourse, you have the freedom to check anything if not just paranthesis.